# PHP Retrieve records from data base using LIMIT and OFFSET with ORDER BY id

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I m trying to retrieve records from DB using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` which works fine, but when I add `ORDER BY id` to it at the end, it fails.

**My code goes as: (this one works fine)**

```
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat = 'category' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0";
    $result6 = $conn->query($sql6);
        if ($result6->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row6 = $result6->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo $row6["position"];
} } else{}
```

**While after adding ORDER it doesn't show any record:**

```
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat = 'category' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result6 = $conn->query($sql6);
        if ($result6->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row6 = $result6->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo $row6["position"];
} } else{}
```

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Check the order of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. `Limit` Should be after `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` must be at the end of the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat = 'category'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET  0
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

> SELECT
>       [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
>         [HIGH_PRIORITY]
>         [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
>         [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
>         [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
>       select_expr [, select_expr ...]
>       [FROM table_references
>       [WHERE where_condition]
>       [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
>         [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
>       [HAVING where_condition]
>       [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
>         [ASC | DESC], ...]
>       [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
>       [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
>       [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
>           [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
>           export_options
>         | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
>         | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
>       [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]

BTW: Check for errors after executing a statement

Comment: @ScienceGeek Have you use the error function to see if you have an error in your query?

Comment: @ScienceGeek How do you know it if you do not check it?